# UILabel not triggering touchesBegan

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

i'm currently struggling to make touchesBegan work.

I currently have this setup

```
[UIView(UIViewController) -> UIScrollView -> UIView[holderView] -> UILabels[]]
```

I add programmatically my `UILabels` this way

```m
//UIViewController method
UILabel *etiquetaCantidad = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, idx * 35, 50, 30)];
[etiquetaCantidad setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[etiquetaCantidad setBackgroundColor:[UIColor azulBase]];
[etiquetaCantidad setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[etiquetaCantidad.layer setCornerRadius:5];
[etiquetaCantidad setText:@"0"];
[etiquetaCantidad setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[etiquetaCantidad setTag:idx + 100];
[holderView addSubview:etiquetaCantidad];
```

But when i try

```m
// UIViewController 
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    NSLog(@"Touch realizado: %@", touches);

}
```

It's not being triggered, what i've missed here???

Comment: What class contains the `touchesBegan` method?

Comment: it's not the uilabel's fault.  Your view has to have touches enabled.

Comment: @badweasel i've updated my question to cover your doubts

Comment: @CleverError the touchesBegan method is contained in the superview

Comment: @badweasel do "userInteractionEnabled" is the thing you mention???

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  Yes that's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling with my problem, the issue was caused by the `UIScrollView` that lies between my `UILabel`s and my `UIViewController`

So i've implemented a category for `UIScrollView` that passes touches to it's super or `nextResponder`

```
#import "UIScrollView+TouchesBeganPropagable.h"

@implementation UIScrollView (TouchesBeganPropagable)

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(!self.dragging){
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }else{
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (!self.dragging){
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else{
        [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (!self.dragging){
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else{
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
    }
}

@end
```

That way, i can use touchesXXXX methods on my `UIViewController` that interact with any `UIView` no matter if an `UIScrollView` is in the middle